# Table with several titles

Tags: html, html-table

I want to creat a table with several titles to highlight different areas.

Basically, the structure needs to look like that:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Title 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Title 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 5</td>
    <td>Col 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 7</td>
    <td>Col 8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 8</td>
    <td>Col 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I'm not sure, whether it's valid code.

Is there a proper tag for the title?

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w124krqw/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper way would be like this, using `th` with a `colspan` of 2 to span the 2 columns.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Title 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Title 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 5</td>
    <td>Col 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 7</td>
    <td>Col 8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 8</td>
    <td>Col 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `<th>` tag for the title.

**UPD** By the way, you can check whether the code is valid or not by using this [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea)

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Title 1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 3</td>
    <td>Col 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Title 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 5</td>
    <td>Col 6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 7</td>
    <td>Col 8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 8</td>
    <td>Col 10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```